# Understanding Post request responses in React

Tags: reactjs, post, asp.net-web-api, postman, fetch-api

In my React app I make a post request to an ASP.Net Core Web API that I made :

```
fetch('https://localhost:44326/api/Players/post', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        handle: data.handle,
        role: data.role,
        avatar: linkToAvatar,
      }),
    }).then((response) => console.log(response.body));
```

This post method executes successfully and a new record is added to the DB. However, I need the ID of the player record that was just created.

If I make this post request in Postman to this address: https://localhost:44326/api/Players/post with the body

```
{
  "handle": "Cole",
  "role": "Fixer",
  "avatar": "null"
}
```

It sends back this response body

```
{
    "id": 58,
    "handle": "Cole",
    "role": "Fixer",
    "avatar": "null",
    "specialAbilities": null,
    "stats": null
}
```

Which is exactly what I am trying to get in React.

As you can see in my fetch method I am trying to access this:

```
.then((response) => console.log(response.body));
```

But the response.body does not look like it does in Postman. Instead it looks like this:

```
ReadableStream {locked: false}
locked: false
[[Prototype]]: ReadableStream
cancel: ƒ cancel()
getReader: ƒ getReader()
locked: (...)
pipeThrough: ƒ pipeThrough()
pipeTo: ƒ pipeTo()
tee: ƒ tee()
constructor: ƒ ReadableStream()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "ReadableStream"
get locked: ƒ locked()
[[Prototype]]: Object
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
__proto__: (...)
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

EDIT: Based on first comment I have tried this:

If I try `console.log(response.json()));` it gives me this:

```
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object
avatar: "https://cyberpunkv2.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/avatars/cyberpunk-logo-3.jpeg"
handle: "Iggy Dog Yo"
id: 61
role: "Rockerboy"
specialAbilities: null
stats: null
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

So here I can see the ID I need, but how exactly can I get to that ID to assign it to a variable?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
`response.json()`

Comment: @Khalt I edited my question to reflect what you have recommended. Thank you a ton! I'm a lot closer now.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this, but I did this:

```
      console.log(response.json().then((data) => setNewID(data.id)))
```

and was able to setNewID to the correct ID.